# Converting a BNF grammar to JavaCC

Tags: grammar, bnf, javacc

I wrote the following JavaCC code from a BNF grammar:

```
TOKEN: {
  <NEXPR: <NTERM> ((<ADD> | <SUB>) <NTERM>)*> |
  <NTERM: <NFACTOR> ((<MUL> | <DIV>) <NFACTOR>)*> |
  <NFACTOR: (<SUB>)? (<DIGIT> | <REPCOUNT> | <PARAMETER> | <LPAR> <NEXPR> <RPAR>)>
}
```

I recive an error from javacc:

> Loop in regular expression detected: "...NEXPR... --> ...NTERM... -->
>   ...NFACTOR... --> ...NEXPR..."

I think my grammar is not left-recursion, anyway, I read that JavaCC doesn't support a left-recursion grammar, so I need to convert that code in a right-recursion one. Now I know the following principle:
This grammar (left recursion)

```
X -> Xa | b
```

Becomes (right recursion):

```
X -> bX'
X' -> aX' | {}
```

or (adapted to JavaCC situation)

```
X -> b(a)*
```

But I don't know how can I convert my example since it's formed by three rules. Can you help me, please?
Initial grammar (BNF form):

```
NExpr      = NTerm { ( "+" | "-" )  NTerm }

NTerm      = NFactor { ( "*" | "/" ) NFactor }

NFactor    = "-" ( Number | REPCOUNT | Parameter | "(" NExpr ")" ) | 
                   Number | REPCOUNT | Parameter | "(" NExpr ")"
```

Comment: Parameter is not relevant to understand the situation. It's a simple string

Comment: Problem is the NEXPR in NFACTOR that cause an infinity loop

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking about a different parser generator.

Comment: But your problem is not left-recursion.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Maybe right recursion or something related to it... is 6 hours I'm trying to overcome this problem

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to make your grammar a single token. Token regular expressions cannot be recursive. But tokens are supposed to be simple things: numbers, identifiers, operators. The grammar itself can be recursive as long as it is not left-recursive.

Comment: Woow this is a good news. So if I write directly Java Code using the grammary I defined, recursion would work?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can sleep quietly :-) I will try in that manner in next days and I will tell you the situation. Thank you again

Comment: You might want to check my tutorial on JavaCC. It shows how to solve a similar problem. https://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell At first glance, well cleaned and structured congratulations! I will read this your tutorial before rewriting the grammar in Java

Comment: The thing is you don't have to rewite the grammar in Java you can use JavaCC's BNF productions.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I explained myself wrong "...before write the grammar (using simple tokens) in a real Java method"

Comment: Thank you very much guys. You helped me. Thanks rici about the problem of recursion and thank you Theodore because your tutorial is awesome! Now all works fine!!